# How to have unshared stateful variables in Go?

Tags: static, go

I know that, right now (and probably forever), we won't have static variables in Go... but is there a way to protect variables in some way?

```
import (
    "net/http"
    "net/http/cookiejar"
)

func funcThatDoesRequests(request Request) (response Response, e error){
  static cookieJar, _ := cookiejar.New(nil)
  static client := http.Client{ Jar: cookieJar }
  response, e = client.Do(handshakeRequest)
  return
}
```

I don't want the http `client` and its `cookieJar` floating around so other functions can do something with them. I need the `cookieJar` and `client` to only be accessible inside the `funcThatDoesRequests`. Is that possible?

> [Static variables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_variable) (see static keyword in the pseudo code example) is a feature present in languages like C and PHP, to name some common languages.

Comment: Would be nice to know why the downvote... I guess the word "stateful" sounds like an "heresy" to some.

Comment: Why not put your variables on a struct and change your function to a method of that struct ? If you don't want other functions to access your variable, make a package : only the functions in that package can access private variables.

Comment: That is a dead-strange question. You know that local variables are local variables? Or do you want to disallow http.Client to access the jar? If yes, how would that work?

Comment: BTW I'm not the downvoter but it might be related to the fact this really looks like [a XY question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) : there are clean ways to do what you need (objects or package private variables).

Comment: @dstroy new to Go here, would be nice to see an answer.

Comment: @Volker the `cookieJar` and `client` are in the same scope, so they can see each other. I'm not talking about local variables, I'm talking about static variables.

Comment: @Volker also "You know that local variables are local variables?" is the real dead-strange question here, IMMO xD

Comment: The problem with the question as stated is that it assumes knowledge of what a static automatic variable is in C.

Comment: What are static variables in Go? There are no. So: Why not use a (unexported) global and don't mess with it?  Trying to program APL in Java fails

Comment: @Volker, sorry I don't like to use Java. BTW, java has no static variables, only static class members (totally different things).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually it's best not to worry about package-scoped globals since it's only code in your own package that can abuse them.

But if you really want, you can use a closure which is created when your package is loaded to generate the "static" variables.

```
func makeFunc() func(req Request)(Response, error) {
    cookieJar, _ := cookiejar.New(nil)
    client := http.Client{Jar: cookieJar}
    return func(req Request)(Response, error) {
        return client.Do(handshakeRequest)
    }
}

var funcThatDoesRequests = makeFunc()
```

Now `funcThatDoesRequests` maintains `client` and `cookieJar` over multiple calls, but the names don't leak into the package.

Comment: Does that look like a best practice ?

Comment: @dystroy you said that the same thing could be achieved with a struct owning a method... but how? I still don't get what you said up there :)

Comment: @Anonymous really nice trick, I'm inclined to accept this if no one provides a less tricky solution.

Comment: @dystroy I suggest the idiomatic version of this code in the first sentence. But it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @Anonymous The reason for the question is that I had a problem with someone else helping to maintain an API client and the person used `cookieJar.SetCookie` but shouldn't have done that. So I decided to find a way to explicitly impede access to the jar and client itself.

Comment: @marcioAlmada Would adding the comment `// Just for use by funcThatDoesRequests` by the global work? If not, I suggest unplugging the person's keyboard :)

Answer (score 1):

One possibility would be to create a struct with your "private, static" variables and make your handler a method of that struct.

```
type privateData struct {
    jar *cookiejar.Jar
    client http.Client
}

func (r *privateData) Initialize() {
    r.jar = cookiejar.New(nil)
    r.client = http.Client{Jar: r.jar}
}

func (r *privateData) Do (request Request) (response Response, e error) {
    /* Rest of the code goes here */
}

/* then, somewhere... */
var thing privateData
thing.Initialize()
/* then you can pass thing.Do where you would have passed funcThatDoesRequests */
```

Comment: Is this better than @Anonymous answer in some way?

Comment: They're about as good, it basically boils down to "what do you find more readable".